# Module Prestashop 1.7 : Custom image upload always replaced

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

My file_url field is always erased in Database if I don't select it. (even if an image is already integrated)

[image]

*If I click Save in this situation, the field PC Image is deleted.*

Here is my `postImage()` method in my `AdminCustomController`

```
 protected function postImage($id)
    {


        $file = isset($_FILES['file_url']) ? $_FILES['file_url'] : false;



        if ($file && is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {


            $path = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'custom/img/';
            $tmp_arr = explode('.', $file['name']);
            $filename = $file['name'];



            if (!Tools::copy($file['tmp_name'], $path . $filename)) {
                $errors[] = Tools::displayError('Failed to load image');
            }

        }
}
```

And here is the renderForm()

```
public function renderForm()
    {
      $image_url = '';

       if($this->object->file_url) {
            $image_url = ImageManager::thumbnail(
                _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'homecase/img/' . $this->object->file_url,
                $this->table . $this->object->file_url,
                150,
                'jpg',
                true,
                true
            );
        }
        $this->fields_form = [
            //Entête
            'legend' => [
                'title' => $this->module->l('Edition'),
                'icon' => 'icon-cog'
            ],

                array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'label' => $this->l('PC Image'),
                    'name' => 'file_url',
                    'display_image' => true,
                    'image' => $image_url ? $image_url : false,
                ),

....
```

The upload and the save in DB is OK. But when the image exists and I don't select an other in the field. The `file_url` field is erased in the DB.

Could you help me?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if an image was uploaded and only after that update your DB records. So, just try to add `return false;` to your `postImage`method and that check before your DB update like

`if ($this->postImage($id) !== false){
    //update image record
}`